# Require check after math operation ^0.8

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, require, math

I'm going over some protocol contracts, and I've seen they check pretty obvious math operations with a *require()* statement. This contract uses solidity **0.8.11**

```
uint256 id = vaultCount;
vaultCount = vaultCount + 1;
require(vaultCount >= id);
```

What is the reason for this? I understand that this was needed before 0.8 due to under and overflows. But why is it needed now?

Comment: Good reading on the subject: [Solidity Learning: Revert(), Assert(), and Require() in Solidity, and the New REVERT Opcode in the EVM](https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e)

Comment: Furthermore: [Custom Errors in Solidity](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/)

Comment: Which contract refers this piece of code?

Comment: The only problem I see in the snippet is that `vaultCount + 1` could cause an overflow, but that should be covered by solc 0.8. Perhaps they upgraded from a previous version and didn't remove the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 explanations, both of which are more of excuses than justifications

1. They wrote the contracts for Solidity < 0.8, which means it wouldn't have built-in overflow checking. Then when they ported to 0.8.11, they didn't notice this (I have been guilty of this in the past.)
2. They just don't know that Solidity >= 0.8 has built in overflow checking

To be extra clear, to answer your question, it absolutely isn't necessary, and it's wasting gas redoing a check that the compiler already did